# Select N previous and M next items around current item id

Tags: mysql

I have a table with photos

```
id | year| comm_count
 0   2015         1
 1   2016         2
 2   2017         5
 3   2018         7
 4   2019         1
 5   2020         9
 6   2021         1
 7   2022         1
```

I select photo with a given id, somewhere in the middle of all photos. For example like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM photo 
WHERE year > '2017' 
ORDER BY comm_count DESC, year DESC
```

This will give me:

```
5,3,7,6,4
```

This gives me list of all photos. Now, I write this list on my web, but user can click on one certain photo. After that, detailed page opens. But from this detailed page, I would like to be able to go to "next" M and "previous" N photos. This means, I need to select neihboring IDs based on currenttly selected one. How can this be done?

Now I select `id = 7` and I want neighbors to be:
`prev: 5,3` and `next: 6,4`. How can this be selected?

SqlFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4f3f42/4/0

I cannot run the same query and filter results in PHP, because query can contain LIMITS (eg. with `LIMIT 2, 4` I still the need correct neighbors)

Comment: You already have the information you need, no? You told us you have the list `5,3,7,6,4`. So your application already knows what surrounds the middle value.

Comment: App knows it, but user can go directly to detailed page and in that case, I dont have the information.

Comment: Okay, I'm with you now.

Comment: You could store the query results (ids only, as an array) inside session var and display pagination based on that list.

Comment: I am doing this, but as I wrote before, if user goes directly to the detailed page, I dont have this info.

Comment: @martin interesting. In that case you could run the query (the one used on master page) again to generate pagination data.

Comment: @SalmanA Yes, but the query I have posted here is simplified, the real query selects more data (and over several tables) and since detailed page is used more often, it would lead to a slow down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the `year` and `comm_count` values for the selected row with id=7, you can make two simple queries:

```
SELECT * FROM photo 
WHERE year > 2017 AND (comm_count = 1 AND year <= 2022 OR comm_count < 1) 
ORDER BY comm_count DESC, year DESC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1
+----+------+------------+
| id | year | comm_count |
+----+------+------------+
|  6 | 2021 |          1 |
|  4 | 2019 |          1 |
+----+------+------------+

SELECT * FROM photo 
WHERE year > 2017 AND (comm_count = 1 AND year >= 2022 OR comm_count > 1) 
ORDER BY comm_count ASC, year ASC LIMIT 3 OFFSET 1;
+----+------+------------+
| id | year | comm_count |
+----+------+------------+
|  3 | 2018 |          7 |
|  5 | 2020 |          9 |
+----+------+------------+
```

If you use MySQL 8.0, you can use the [LAG() and LEAD() functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag).

```
SELECT id, year, 
  LAG(id, 1) OVER w AS next,
  LAG(id, 2) OVER w AS next_next,
  LEAD(id, 1) OVER w AS prev,
  LEAD(id, 2) OVER w AS prev_prev
FROM photo 
WHERE year > 2017
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY comm_count DESC, year DESC)

+----+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
| id | year | next | next_next | prev | prev_prev |
+----+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
|  5 | 2020 | NULL |      NULL |    3 |         7 |
|  3 | 2018 |    5 |      NULL |    7 |         6 |
|  7 | 2022 |    3 |         5 |    6 |         4 |
|  6 | 2021 |    7 |         3 |    4 |      NULL |
|  4 | 2019 |    6 |         7 | NULL |      NULL |
+----+------+------+-----------+------+-----------+
```

Comment: How comes, `prev` and `prev_prev` are always equal? And shouldn't there be a `year > 2017` condition?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel, My mistake, I copy & pasted the wrong content. I've edited to fix it in my answer, after re-running the query and getting the correct output.